# YouTrack Ticket Template

Tags: youtrack

is there a way to have project-wide task templates for each task type or static templates in YouTrack? I only find something like "issue template url" and that`s a little bit circuitous.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are basically two options:

1. Create a workflow rule that would paste a certain description and set certain field values to the issue. [Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/incloud/Workflow-Default-Description.html) you can see an example of such workflow. You can customize the workflow according to your needs, for example, create a separate rule for each issue type.
   You can also make a series of templates in [action rules](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/devportal/action-rules.html), which will let you use different templates by selecting the corresponding action from the toolbar.
2. Create a draft of an issue that you'd like to make a template for a particular issue type, then [generate an issue template URL](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/incloud/Generate-Issue-Template-URL.html) (that's right) and share with anyone who might need it.